# How to get xdmp:tidy() to tidy up HTML5?

Tags: tidy, marklogic

With the new doctype and elements that are part of HTML5, how do you get `xdmp:tidy()` to recognize those in HTML5?

If I have an html page that contains something like:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <header>blah</header>
    <section>blah</section>
```

and then try something like:
`xdmp:tidy(xdmp:document-get("home.html"))`

I get errors like:

```
<section> is not recognized! discarding unexpected <section>
<header> is not recognized! discarding unexpected <header>
```

Are there some options I can send to `xdmp:tidy()` to get it to handle it?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the *new-blocklevel-tags* option that specifies the new HTML5 tags. You can include multiple elements by separating them with a comma or space. You should get the expected output with no errors, but there will still be warnings.

Try this in cq:

`xdmp:tidy(xdmp:document-get("home.html"), <options xmlns="xdmp:tidy"><new-blocklevel-tags>header section</new-blocklevel-tags></options>)`

Click [here](http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/quickref.html#new-blocklevel-tags) for a good reference about adding various tags (block level, inline, empty) that should work as options in xdmp:tidy. The same information is [here](http://api.xqueryhacker.com/?4.2#xdmp%3atidy), but it's a bit harder to get to, there's so many options!

Comment: I tried your suggestion but now I get:
`    <warning line="68" column="9">&lt;section&gt; is not approved by W3C</warning>
`    <warning line="73" column="9">&lt;header&gt; is not approved by W3C</warning>

Answer (score 1):

The rest of this discussion moved over to the marklogic mailing list at http://markmail.org/thread/emwua43mg63wxbno

---

This does produce warnings but seems to work nonetheless:

xquery version "1.0-ml";

```
let $htmlstring :=
'<html>
    <header>blah</header>
    <section>blah</section>
<p>hello</p>
</html>'
return
xdmp:tidy($htmlstring,
<options xmlns="xdmp:tidy">
  <new-inline-tags>header section</new-inline-tags>
  <new-blocklevel-tags>header section</new-blocklevel-tags>
</options>)
```